# The etymology of "religion" comes from "legere" meaning to read + "re" meaning again. Or does it? (more inside)

Tags: etymology, language-evolution, ambiguity, religion, roots

The etymology of religion as mentioned in the title comes from Etymonline.

And that's very interesting. It makes sense too.

My question is, how do the phrases, "to read", "to choose", "to gather", "law", and "to bind" all come together to form the phonetic root "leg"/"lig" which constitutes the etymology of "religion". Or do they at all? Also, is there any meaning to the whole "leg" (body part) thing? Does this have something to do with legs and free will? Because that would be interesting.

Other roots with 'legere'

```
- "intelligence". 'intere': "between" + 'legere': "choose, pick out, read". [2]
- "legal": 'legere':"to gather" or 'lex':"law". [3]
- "ligament": L 'ligamentum': "to bind, tie". [4]
```

So, given this background, what do you know about the etymology of the word "religion", the meaning(s) of "legere", and, perhaps most importantly, the legitimacy of Etymonline as a source?

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=religion&searchmode=none
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=intelligence&searchmode=none
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=leg&searchmode=none
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ligament&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here. Is this just a peeve against Etymonline? If you have a real question about the etymology of _religion_, I suggest phrasing it more succinctly. Also, all these highlighted URLs hurt my head—just highlight your key words and embed them as links please.

Comment: French SE has a similar question: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/7037/1995

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Religion** comes from Latin *religio*; many people from Cicero onwards have speculated about the origin of *religio*, but there is no known answer.

*Legere* meant originally 'to pick out', and went by a fairly obvious route to 'to read'.

You will have to make your own mind up about etymonline.com; like most sources it is useful if you understand it but not if you just copy it blindly.

The rest of your question would be very welcome on Latin.SE but isn't really on-topic here.

Comment: Also *ligare* (meaning *to bind* or *tie*) and *legere* (meaning *to pick out*) are two **different** Latin verbs which have given rise to similar-sounding words in English.

Comment: Does Latin.SE exist?

Comment: @Dan: actually, there is a proposal in Area 51, at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21061/latin-language-usage. (You could go there and support it.)  But I meant only that the fact that there is not yet a Stack Exchange site where a question fits does not stop it being off-topic here.

Answer (score 6):

The question makes a false assumption in claiming etymonline.com says:

> The etymology of “religion” comes from “legere” meaning to read + “re” meaning again.

Read the [etymonline.com entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=religion&allowed_in_frame=0) again, it only says for certain that English "religion" comes from Latin *religio* (via Anglo-French and Old French). Beyond this, it offers three possible different roots:

1. *re+legere* "read again", according to Cicero
2. *religare* "to bind fast", according to later ancients (and many modern writers)
3. *religiens* "careful"